# Ionic 3 - Push-plugin Error: String resource ID #0x0 when safariViewController Installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, auth0, sfsafariviewcontroller

Basicly this questions is for getting some guidance about this issue and how to solve it.

I'm getting this error with `phonegap-plugin-push` after I try to use `cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller` in the proyect, when the app loads the `phonegap-plugin-push` won't be able to initialize the `push.on` functions so will give this error `String resource ID #0x0`. I'm trying to build an app with notifications and auth0 login, which is why I need these plugins.

According this issue https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1800 `phonegap-plugin-push` will work if `safariviewcontroller` plugin is not installed. But `safariviewcontroller` is a requisite for reproducing the example given in Auth0 https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic2/01-login

Is there any alternative to use Auth0 in ionic without installing `safariviewcontroller`?

Is it possible to authenticate with Auth0 using inappbrowser in ionic 3+?

Comment: Please check the order in which the plugins are added to the platform.  I get the same error when the push plugin is first but it worked if the push plugin was installed last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by uninstalling the `safariviewcontroller` plugin and just using the `WebAuth` library alone.